# Problems using a function as an argument

Tags: functions, function-construction

I made a function:
f[x_]:=x^2+1

and when i use it on, for example f[5], i get the answer 26.

.

But when i use it on:

PollardRho[a_, f_] := Module[

{},

Return[f[a]]

]

And when i write PollardRho[5,f[x]]

It somehow returns (1 + x^2)[5] instead of 26, so now...why?

Comment: I quit the kernel, and it still returns (1+x^2)[5]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Try `PollardRho[5,f]`

Comment: That's it. Now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `f` as a [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html)

```
f = #^2 + 1 &;

PollardRho[a_, f_] := f[a]

PollardRho[5, f]

(*  26  *)
```

Answer (score 7):

I know that Michael E2 has already answered your question, but I wanted to expand why it works. When Mathematica evaluates your code, it does so recursively so that innermost expressions are (usually) evaluated before outermost expressions.

When you typed in `PollardRho[5, f[x]]`, the evaluation routine turned it into `PollardRho[5, 1+x^2]` because that is what f[x] would normally evaluate to.

Then the `PollardRho[5, 1+x^2]` evaluated using pattern matching, and your function literally added the head `(1+x^2)` in front of the argument 5. In this case, `1+x^2` is not a function that can be applied, so the full expression `(1+x^2)[5]` was returned to you.

The way to avoid this is to make sure that if one of your arguments is supposed to be a function that is evaluated on other arguments, that you only pass in the name of the function. As someone answered, this means using `PollardRho[5, f]` instead of `PollardRho[5, f[x]]` (or anything else in lieu of the x for that matter).